# css files are not loaded when I am using production mode with Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django app. And I try to simulate production envrionment.

So I have splitted the settings in three seperate files: local , prod and base.

Part of the base.py looks like:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from os import environ
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG') == "False"



STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = [
     (BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR /'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS =['zijn']

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR /'media'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR/'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And the manage.py file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys
from zijn.settings import base



def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    
    if base.DEBUG:
       os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'zijn.settings.local')
    else:
        os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'zijn.settings.production')
  
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this works if I set DEBUG to False. I get this output:

```
Django version 4.2.3, using settings 'zijn.settings.production'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

But in production mode the css is not loaded. in dev tools I see the following errors:

```
GET
http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/admin/js/theme.js

GET
http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js

The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/admin/js/theme.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
admin
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

url.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from drf_spectacular.views import (SpectacularAPIView, SpectacularSwaggerView)

from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('zijnAdmin.urls')),         
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('schema/', get_schema_view()),
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='api-schema'),
    path('api/docs', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='api-schema'), name='api-docs'),
    path('api/user/',include('accounts.urls') )    
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
   + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in local mode everyting works fine.

Question: So how to run Production mode with the css loaded?

Comment: So can I test production mode on localhost?

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: @JensV. Yes, I did that. So only some admin css and js files are not loaded. What I posted. And I see the staticfiles folder has been created with the admin folder in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Django is not responsible for serving your static files. You need to handle that by yourself. You can do that by using any third party services like AWSS3, bunnyCDN etc. You can also configure your nginx or apache server to serve static files from your own server.

However If you are still trying to test your code on localhost, try Adding static url to your urlpatterns. this might solve your problem

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: #pi3o1416.Yes, I have done that. But apparently doesn't work.

Comment: Try starting your development server with --insecure flag
"python manage.py runserver --insecure"
This will force django to serve static file even when DEBUG is False. However this is only for test perpose and not recommanded for production server. In production static files should be handled by yourself. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#runserver) for detail.

Answer (score 1):

By default django in production mode cant access static and media file from local env.

Use AWS, Wasabi, Blackblaze or Azure Bucket to store your static files and uploaded media files